# How can I prevent this daily countdown timer from resetting at midnight?

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs, countdown

**Key variables to keep in mind:**

This is set to simulate 11:00 PM.
`var bt = "23:00";`
This is set to simulate 8:00 AM.
`var wt = "08:00";`

**The desired functionality:**

- The countdown timer starts every morning at 8:00 AM.
- It counts down until 11:00 PM, every night.
- Then it stays at 00:00:00.
- In the morning, at 8:00 AM, it repeats the count-down, again.
- This should happen forever.

**What is actually happening:**

- Everything is working fine, except it is starting a 24 hour countdown at midnight, until 8:00 AM.

I have tried debugging this, and I suspect the error lies in what is calculated as the `distance` variable, making the code think that it is comparing against the next day, but I am not sure how to remedy this.

Here is the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ammarrai/pen/RYbxpe).

and here is my JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var bt = "23:00";  // 11:00 PM
    var wt = "08:00";  // 08:00 AM

    var dateNow = moment().format('MMM D, YYYY');
    placeHolderDate = dateNow + " " + bt;

    var timeNow = moment().format('HH:mm');

    var countDownDate = new Date(placeHolderDate).getTime();

    var countDownHourMin = (wt.split(":"));


// Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function () {


        // Get todays date and time
        var now = new Date().getTime();

        // Find the distance between now and the count down date
        var distance = countDownDate - now;

        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        $("#countDown").val(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);

        // If the countdown is over, write some text
        if (hours === 0 && minutes === 0 && seconds === 0) {
            //clearInterval(x);
            $("#countDown").val("00:00:00");
        }

        if (hours < 0 || minutes < 0 || seconds < 0) {
            //clearInterval(x);
            $("#countDown").val("00:00:00");
        }
        var timeNow = moment().format('HH:mm');
        //console.log('Time Now:' + timeNow);
        //console.log('Wake Time:' + wt);
        if (timeNow === wt) {
            clearInterval(x);
            restartCountdown();
        }


        //console.log(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);

    }, 1000);


    function restartCountdown() {
        //log("restartCountdown Started!");

    var bt = "23:00";  // 11:00 PM
    var wt = "08:00";  // 08:00 AM

        var dN = (moment().add(moment.duration({d: 1})).format('MMM D, YYYY'));
        console.log('dn ' + dN);

        var placeHolderDate = dN + " " + bt;
        var countDownDate = new Date(placeHolderDate).getTime();

        var countDownHourMin = (wt.split(":"));


        // Update the count down every 1 second
        var x = setInterval(function () {

            // Get todays date and time
            var now = new Date().getTime();

            // Find the distance between now and the count down date
            var distance = countDownDate - now;

            // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

            $("#countDown").val(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);

            // If the countdown is over, write some text
            if (hours === 0 && minutes === 0 && seconds === 0) {
                //clearInterval(x);
                $("#countDown").val("00:00:00");
            }

            if (hours < 0 || minutes < 0 || seconds < 0) {
                //clearInterval(x);
                $("#countDown").val("00:00:00");
            }

            //  console.log(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);

        }, 1000);

    }
});
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you want it to stop between `23:00 - 08:00`. Which lines are to do that job? It's contradicting with your `if (timeNow === wt)`, which `restartCountdown` restarts it right away.

Comment: @choz
Correct. I want for it to stop between 23:00 - 08:00 - or at least, display 00:00:00, visually, to the user. The `if` statement is actually starting it correctly, at 08:00 AM. Also, please note that the `wt` and `bt` can be changed in the actual app, and are hard-coded here for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited your code and created this codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aabjEb?editors=0010. Please feel free to optimize the code since I have not done it. The idea was is check if time is between 8 AM and 11 PM. If yes show value else show 00:00:00. Also once the date changes, update the dates and now compute accordingly

$(document).ready(function () {

```
  function countdown() {
     var bt = "23:00",  // 11:00 PM
         wt = "08:00";  // 08:00 AM


    var today = new Date(),
        dd = today.getDate(),
        mm = today.getMonth()+1,
        yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    var startTime = new Date(mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy + ' ' + wt),
        endTime = new Date(mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy + ' ' + bt);

    setInterval(function() {
       var now = new Date();
       var nowdd = today.getDate();
       var nowTime = now.getTime();
      if(dd !== nowdd) {
        dd = nowdd;
        var nowmm = now.getMonth() + 1,
            nowyyyy = now.getFullYear();
        startTime = new Date(dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy + ' wt');
        endTime = new Date(dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy + ' bt');
      }

      if(nowTime > startTime && nowTime < endTime) {
         // Find the distance between now and the count down date
            var distance = endTime - nowTime;

            // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)),
                minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)),
                seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
            $("#countDown").val(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
         } else {
           $("#countDown").val("00:00:00");
         }
    }, 1000);
  }
  countdown();
});
```

Comment: There appears to be a bug in this. Try with these times: `bt = "02:30"` and `wt = "09:00"`

Comment: According to the logic and code. wt has to be 2:30 and bt has to be 9:00

Comment: I tried with 2:30 and 9:00, but it's the same result. For example, the time right now is 11:22 PM where I am located. I set bt at 2:00 (AM) and wt at 9:00 (AM) but the counter still shows 00:00:00

Comment: ok, so that means 9:00 AM of day 1 and 2 AM of day 2. In that case, you need to add a day to endTime

Comment: Right now, the following scenario works fine: 11pm (day 1)- 8am (day 2), but it stumbles at 2am (day 2) - 8am (day 2). Would I be able to account for this scenario dynamically in my app? where the user only gives these two times, without specifying which day. i.e. the algorithm would be smart enough to "know" that the 2 AM refers to the 2 AM that hasn't arrived yet.

Comment: I have edited the codepen so instead of providing end time you mention number of hours post the start time you want the counter to run. This will take care of the fact when the day changes